# Android Google Maps component showing less detail than Official Google Maps app

Tags: maps

My app contains a Google Map component, showing the maps of an Airport

When the user Zooms right into the map on the Official Google Maps app, it shows the names of the shops, bars, restaurants, etc.

When the user Zooms right into the map in my own app, it doesn't show the names of the shops, etc. It shows symbols for phones, ATMs, elevators, etc, but no indication of what shops are in the airport.

Is this intentional on the part of Google or is there some way of showing these shop names?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) to achieve the same.